# getting Fatal Error while trying to start laravel server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

i'm trying to start my laravel 5.5 server using the `php artisan serve` command.

but i'm getting `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`

it is the first time to happen and nothing is working from php artisan commands to.

Comment: You don't write any code after installation??

Comment: of course , i've been working on this project for 1 month and the last time was yesterday and it was fine.

Comment: Check your routes/web.php . I think you missed somethings in youre routes.

Comment: Assuming you have version control since you've been working on it for a month. Check out a previous commit and see it it's fixed.

Comment: copy paste full error stack trace, xor file that error references to

Comment: yep , thank you the problem was in the route file.
@MahfuzShishir